# Some items not showing up in ItemsControl via ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, itemscontrol, itemssource

I'm trying to get an ItemsControl, which contains a grid, to display 9 checkboxes with different properties. However, only three ever show up.

I have a checkbox model class which has four properties representing the checkboxs' content, grid.row/column, and isChecked properties. I then create nine of these in my viewmodel and add them to an `ObservableCollection`.

Next I bind the ItemsSource of my ItemsControl to the collection. Then, I add a checkbox control to the grid inside of the ItemsControl and bind the appropriate properties.

However, only the first three checkboxes are showing up and I have no idea why. I did verify via debugging that the collection being bound to does have the correct number of items.

Here's my CheckboxModel class:

```
public class CheckboxModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool _isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set { _isChecked = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked"); }
    }

    private string _content;
    public string Content
    {
        get { return _content; }
        set { _content = value; OnPropertyChanged("Content"); }
    }

    private int _gridRow;
    public int GridRow
    {
        get { return _gridRow; }
        set { _gridRow = value; OnPropertyChanged("GridRow"); }
    }

    private int _gridColumn;
    public int GridColumn
    {
        get { return _gridColumn; }
        set { _gridColumn = value; OnPropertyChanged("GridColumn"); }
    }

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

In my view model, I create a collection of these:

```
private ObservableCollection<CheckboxModel> _checkBoxList = new ObservableCollection<CheckboxModel>();
public ObservableCollection<CheckboxModel> CheckBoxList
{
    get
    {
        return _checkBoxList;
    }
    set
    {
        if (null != value)
        {
            _checkBoxList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CheckBoxList");
        }
    }
}

public void CreateCheckboxList()
{
    CheckBoxList.Add(new CheckboxModel { IsChecked = true, Content = "Latitude", GridRow = 0, GridColumn = 0  });
    CheckBoxList.Add(new CheckboxModel { IsChecked = true, Content = "Longitude", GridRow = 1, GridColumn = 0 });
    CheckBoxList.Add(new CheckboxModel { IsChecked = true, Content = "Altitude", GridRow = 2, GridColumn = 0 });
    CheckBoxList.Add(new CheckboxModel { IsChecked = true, Content = "Depth", GridRow = 0, GridColumn = 1 });
    CheckBoxList.Add(new CheckboxModel { IsChecked = true, Content = "Speed", GridRow = 1, GridColumn = 1 });
    CheckBoxList.Add(new CheckboxModel { IsChecked = true, Content = "Heading", GridRow = 2, GridColumn = 1 });
    CheckBoxList.Add(new CheckboxModel { IsChecked = true, Content = "Roll", GridRow = 0, GridColumn = 2 });
    CheckBoxList.Add(new CheckboxModel { IsChecked = true, Content = "Pitch", GridRow = 1, GridColumn = 2 });
    CheckBoxList.Add(new CheckboxModel { IsChecked = true, Content = "VOS", GridRow = 2, GridColumn = 2 }); 
}
```

And then finally here's my xaml:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CheckBoxList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="149.6*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="149.6*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="149.6*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="28*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="28*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="28*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <CheckBox Grid.Row="{Binding GridRow}"
                          Grid.Column="{Binding GridColumn}"
                          Margin="14,6,63,6"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Content="{Binding Content}"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Here's what I want it to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that a new Grid is created for each item in your `ObservableCollection` but you want a single Grid for all items.

You could set the `ItemsPanel` of the `ItemsControl` to your `Grid` and use an `ItemContainerStyle` to set the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` attached properties of each item container.

This should work:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CheckBoxList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="149.6*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="149.6*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="149.6*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="28*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="28*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="28*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding GridRow}" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding GridColumn}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Margin="14,6,63,6"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Content="{Binding Content}"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

[image]

Comment: @pdinferno `UniformGrid` would do a great job as an items panel for this one too.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that the missing items are just vertically stacked out of sight. You want a `WrapPanel` for your items panel. You also need to make sure that your ItemsControl isn't auto-sizing itself larger than its parent.

```
<ItemsControl 
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    ItemsSource="{Binding CheckBoxList}">
    <!-- Add this-->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel 
                Orientation="Vertical" 
                />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <!-- Done -->

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="149.6*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="149.6*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="149.6*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="28*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="28*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="28*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <CheckBox Grid.Row="{Binding GridRow}"
                    Grid.Column="{Binding GridColumn}"
                    Margin="14,6,63,6"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Content="{Binding Content}"
                    IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
                    />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```